# Data loading issue on Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I have wrote a flutter code to load questions using a json. This works but when we go to the next question json load again. How to load once.

Other question is I'm loading answers to buttons and when click the answer I need to change that buttons color. Can some one help me.

Thanks

Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'show_question_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class ShowQuestions extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowQuestions({super.key});

  @override
  State<ShowQuestions> createState() => _ShowQuestionsState();
}

class _ShowQuestionsState extends State<ShowQuestions> {
  List<Question> questionList = [];
  int currentQuestionIndex = 0;
  int score = 0;

  Future getQuestionData() async {
      var response = await http
          .get(Uri.http("www.ananmanan.lk", "app/getQuestionList.php"));
      var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<Question> questions = [];
      for (var u in jsonData) {
        Question question = Question(
          u['ques'],
          u['ans1'],
          u['ans2'],
          u['ans3'],
          u['ans4'],
          u['correct_ans'],
        );
        questions.add(question);
      }
      return questions;
  }
  //Answer? selectedAnswer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Question Paper'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getQuestionData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Loading...'),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            questionList = snapshot.data;
            return Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 32),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  _questionWidget(),
                  _answerList(),
                  _nextButton(),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      )),
    );
  }

  _questionWidget() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Question ${currentQuestionIndex + 1}/5}',
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20.0,
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
          child: Text(
            questionList[currentQuestionIndex].ques,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _answerList() {
    bool isCorrectAns = false;
    bool isAns1 = false;
    bool isAns2 = false;
    bool isAns3 = false;
    bool isAns4 = false;

    //bool isSelected = answer == selectedAnswer;
    // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
    // if (questionList[currentQuestionIndex].correctanswer == 1) {
    //   isCorrectAns = true;
    // } else {
    //   isCorrectAns = false;
    // }
    if (questionList[currentQuestionIndex].correct_ans == '1') {
      isAns1 = true;
    } else if (questionList[currentQuestionIndex].correct_ans == '2') {
      isAns2 = true;
    } else if (questionList[currentQuestionIndex].correct_ans == '3') {
      isAns3 = true;
    } else if (questionList[currentQuestionIndex].correct_ans == '4') {
      isAns4 = true;
    }
    return Container(
      // width: double.infinity,
      // margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
      // height: 48,
      child: Column(children: [
        _answerButton(questionList[currentQuestionIndex].ans1, isAns1),
        _answerButton(questionList[currentQuestionIndex].ans2, isAns2),
        _answerButton(questionList[currentQuestionIndex].ans3, isAns3),
        _answerButton(questionList[currentQuestionIndex].ans4, isAns4),
      ]),
    );
  }

  Widget _answerButton(String ansText, bool correctans) {
    //bool isSelected = answer == selectedAnswer;
    bool click = false;

    if (ansText != '') {
      return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
        height: 48,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(ansText),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: const StadiumBorder(),
            primary: click == true ? Colors.orangeAccent : Colors.white,
            onPrimary: click == true ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            if (correctans) {
              score++;
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return SizedBox.shrink();
    }
  }

  _nextButton() {
    bool isLastQuestion = false;
    if (currentQuestionIndex == questionList.length - 1) {
      isLastQuestion = true;
    }
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
      height: 48,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(isLastQuestion ? 'Submit' : 'Next'),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          shape: const StadiumBorder(),
          primary: Colors.blueAccent,
          onPrimary: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          if (isLastQuestion) {
            showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => _showScoreDialog());
          } else {
            setState(() {
              //selectedAnswer = null;
              currentQuestionIndex++;
            });
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _showScoreDialog() {
    bool isPassed = false;

    if (score >= questionList.length * 0.6) {
      isPassed = true;
    }
    String title = isPassed ? 'Passed' : 'Failed';

    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(
        title + ' | Score is $score',
        style: TextStyle(color: isPassed ? Colors.green : Colors.redAccent),
      ),
      content: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Restart'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          setState(() {
            currentQuestionIndex = 0;
            score = 0;
            //selectedAnswer = null;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

1. Stop loading the json multiple times
2. Change the color of the button that selected

Comment: also, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59859523/how-to-fetch-data-only-once-when-using-futurebuilder

Comment: Try this- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61802303/17576172

Comment: How do I change the color of the button. I have done it and but its not working